# Problems authoring a custom Tag Helper for ASP.NET Core in F#

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have been trying to write a custom tag helper and match it to a tag/attribute with `HtmlTargetElementAttribute`, however I've ran into an issue where the tag helper seems to apply to every tag on the page—even those that shouldn't match. The following is a reduced case that I could reproduce it with, and as far as I understand, this should match only on `<test custom>` elements:

```
[<HtmlTargetElement ("test", Attributes = "custom", TagStructure = TagStructure.NormalOrSelfClosing)>]
type CustomTagHelper () =
    inherit TagHelper ()

    override __.Process (_, output) =
        output.Content.SetContent("Test")
        |> ignore
```

Now, if I look at that in something like ILSpy, the `HtmlTargetElementAttribute` displays in C# as:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("test", Attributes = "custom", TagStructure = )]
```

but I'm not sure if that actually affects the IL or if that's just a bug in ILSpy. However, if I actually remove the `TagStructure` parameter, then the tag helper works as I would have expected, only working on `<test>` elements with a `custom` attribute. Additionally, I tried saving the enum value in a separate constant:

```
[<Literal>]
let tagStructure = TagStructure.NormalOrSelfClosing
```

and using that in the attribute, which *does* actually work as well. But then strangely I tried setting that constant to a different enum value, but reverted the attribute definition back to what I had initially, and *that* worked as well.

So now I've only confused myself even more and I've likely missed something simple along the way.

Comment: Well, `NormalOrSelfClosing` is the default, so you should be able to just not bother specifying it at all. (That's also probably why ILSpy is shoiwing it as not set, but don't know for sure.) Regardless, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you have in any of the forms, so if there's some difference in how it's working, you might have stumbled upon a bug. The F# support in ASP.NET Core is relatively new, so it's entirely possible not all the kinks are worked out yet. I'd recommend adding an issue to the Github repo with as much detail as you can manage.

Comment: Hrm, though my problem is that ILSpy *does* show it as being set when I use a separate literal to specify the value, like my last example that works. Also I only came across this issue because I was trying to use it with `WithoutEndTag`, but the same problem occurs regardless of which value I use.